# Solve for the exponent of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

we discussed matrices in class and had the following task: Given

$$U=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & \frac{1}{15} & 0 & 0 & 0 &0\\0 & \frac{8}{15} & \frac{3}{15} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac{6}{15} & \frac{9}{15} & \frac{6}{15} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{15} & \frac{8}{15} & \frac{10}{15} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{15} & \frac{5}{15} & 1\end{bmatrix},
\quad \overrightarrow{s}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},$$

solve for $x$ such that $U^x\overrightarrow{s}=\overrightarrow{s_x}$ where the last element (Row) of $\overrightarrow{s_x}$ should be equal or greater than 0.99.

We were told that the only way to get $x$ is by inserting random numbers and "search" for it. By doing this we actually found:

$$\overrightarrow{s_{15}}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0,0137\\0,9863\end{bmatrix},\quad \overrightarrow{s_{16}}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0,0091\\0,9909\end{bmatrix}.$$

So the answer is pretty much $x=16$, but is there no way to solve for $x$ instead of inserting random numbers until you find the answer?

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Is $\overrightarrow{s}$ a column vector? If so how can the top element of the product be $1,$ as all entries of top row of matrix are $0$ ?

Comment: yes $\overrightarrow{s}$ is a column vector. Can you clarify what you mean with the top element of the product is 1? The product of $U^{15}*\overrightarrow{s}=\overrightarrow{s_{15}}$

Comment: Oh I get it... the definitions were so close in question it looked like the matrix was multiplying the column vector. But it's just two separate equations, one for what U is, and one for what s is.

Comment: On that note, I've edited your question so as to make it more clear visually.

Comment: Thank you very much @Semiclassical Iam new to this page, so Iam just getting used to the formatting, but that's really nice of you! :) Thanks for taking that time

Comment: You can certainly come up with an expression for the lower-left element of $U^x$, which is what the problem is basically asking you about, but I don’t know of any analytic solution to the resulting inequality, so ultimately you will have to guess or estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

Using [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-diagonalization-calculator/diagonalize%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%260%260%260%260%260%5C%5C%20%201%26%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B15%7D%260%260%260%260%5C%5C%20%200%26%5Cfrac%7B8%7D%7B15%7D%26%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B15%7D%260%260%260%5C%5C%200%20%26%5Cfrac%7B6%7D%7B15%7D%26%5Cfrac%7B9%7D%7B15%7D%26%5Cfrac%7B6%7D%7B15%7D%260%260%5C%5C%200%20%260%26%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B15%7D%26%5Cfrac%7B8%7D%7B15%7D%26%5Cfrac%7B10%7D%7B15%7D%260%5C%5C%200%20%260%260%26%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B15%7D%26%5Cfrac%7B5%7D%7B15%7D%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D) you get the diagonalization of $U=PDP^{-1}$, then $U^x = PDP^{-1} \dots PDP^{-1} = P D^x P^{-1}$ where $D$ is the matrix with the elements of $D$ elevated to power $x$. Using this you can solve for the last element being greater to $0.99$

Comment: i actually found a function that does exactly what i want with your approach. Thank you very much for this answer! really useful